# Django uploaded file in admin list

Tags: python, django

I've read several posts here on this problem and have tried many of the approaches - in the end I returned to the Django docs.

I'm trying to get the uploaded image to appear in the admin list...

My models.py (based on info from here: [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates))

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.html import format_html

class File(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
    def image_tag(self):
        return format_html(
            '<img src="{}" />', self.file
        )

class FileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('image_tag', 'description')
```

This, sadly, does nothing however...

I have tried putting arbitrary HTML as well - just in case file url is bad...but nothing changes.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated - quite frustrated with this now.

Comment: Have you tried `self.file.url` as the `src`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this in place of `format_html`,

Update `models.py` as follows:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

def image_tag(self):

    if self.file:
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="200" height="200"/>' % self.file)
    else:
        return '(No image found)'

image_tag.short_description = 'Thumb'
```

In your `admin.py` add:

```
list_display= ('image_tag',)
```

There is also a package [django-imagekit](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit) which can be helpful.

Comment: No - that one didn't work either unfortunately. It's very similar to other ones I've found on SO - but it seems the method I outlined above is for the current version (1.11)...but...doesn't work either.

Comment: You can try it with  `mark_safe`. I have updated my answer above.